# ReferenceError: MediaStream is not defined - in unitTest with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, webrtc, mediastream

I am trying to run unit-test with jest framework.
I have some webrtc related code in my project written in typescript.

I am continuously getting this error.
I tried to mock MediaStream but to no avail.

My test file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const configureStore = require('redux-mock-store');


import App from '../App';
import mockData from "../mockData";
const mockStore = configureStore();

describe('Tests related to App', () => {
    it('Capturing Snapshot of App', () => {
        let store = mockStore(mockData.getStore());
        const renderedValue = renderer.create(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>).toJSON();;
        expect(renderedValue).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
})
```

I understand that MediaStream is a platform level property.
So i tried to mock, such that Jest would understand, but to no avail.

My mock code.

```
let mediaStream = {
        getVideoTracks: function() {
            return [];
        }
    }

    const mediaDevicesMock = {
        getUserMedia: jest.fn(() => { return Promise.resolve(mediaStream)})
      };

    global.navigator.mediaDevices = mediaDevicesMock;
```

I may be wrong on multiple levels, any suggestion and rectification is most welcome.
I tried to make sense of this [link](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/issues/7424), but not much could be figured out.

> Jest Version: "^22.1.4"

Answer (score 2):

I have mocked `MediaRecorder` in order to pass test like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'MediaRecorder', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
        start: jest.fn(),
        ondataavailable: jest.fn(),
        onerror: jest.fn(),
        state: '',
        stop: jest.fn()
    }))
});
```

Additionally, I have also mocked the `isTypeSupported` method:

```
Object.defineProperty(MediaRecorder, 'isTypeSupported', {
    writable: true,
    value: () => true
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, according to the documentation, this solution might not work. The docs seem to say that this approach only works if you are calling navigator.mediaDevices directly in your test, which the OP does not seem to be doing. Instead, according to the docs, you would need to put your mock into a separate file and import it at the top of your tests file. https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom

Answer (score 1):

mediaDevices interface is not implemented in JSDOM yet. You might be able to mock it using this code stub from their official documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom